# Spy returns callcount 0 when used as object property

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to write test that checks if third-part library functions has been called.

The test: (mocha)

```
describe('SomeClassTest', () => {
  describe('Setup', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      const channel = {createChannel: () => 'channel created'};
      // @ts-ignore
      this.channelSpy = Sinon.spy(channel, 'createChannel');
      // @ts-ignore
      Sinon.stub(amqplib, 'connect').returns(channel);
  });
    // @ts-ignore
    afterEach(() => amqplib.connect.restore());

    it('Should check if SomeClass has created Channel', () => {
      const someclass = SomeClass.getInstance();
      someclass.init();

      // @ts-ignore
      expect(amqplib.connect.callCount).to.be.eq(1); // True
      // @ts-ignore
      expect(this.channelSpy.callCount).to.be.eq(1); // False :(
    });
  });
});
```

The class:

```
export default class SomeClass {

  private connection?: amqplib.Connection;

  public async init() {
    await this.connect();
    await this.createChannel();
  }

  private async connect(): Promise<void> {
    this.connection = await amqplib.connect(this.connectionOptions);
  }

  private async createChannel(): Promise<void> {
    if (!this.connection) {
      throw new Error('Some Error :)');
    }
    this.channel = await this.connection.createChannel();
  }
}
```

I'm sure that this.connection.createChannel() has been called, but tests don't want to prove it, Would anyone help my poor soul?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `Promise` resolves the callback gets queued in the [PromiseJobs queue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) which gets processed *after the current running message has completed*.

In this case your functions are queuing callbacks in PromiseJobs and the current running message is *the test itself* so the test runs to completion *before the jobs queued in PromiseJobs have a chance to run*.

Because the jobs in PromiseJobs haven't run yet, the test fails when it gets to the test for `channelSpy` since it hasn't been called yet.

---

The `Promise` returned by `init` is already chained to the `Promises` returned by `connect` and `createChannel` so all you have to do is make your test function `async` and then call `await` on the `Promise` returned by `init`:

```ts
it('Should check if SomeClass has created Channel', async () => {  // async test function
  const someclass = SomeClass.getInstance();
  await someclass.init();  // await the Promise returned by init

  // @ts-ignore
  expect(amqplib.connect.callCount).to.be.eq(1); // True
  // @ts-ignore
  expect(this.channelSpy.callCount).to.be.eq(1); // True
});
```